# Multiple Nested Grouping in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, nested

Suppose, for example, in my C# code, I have `MyClass`, defined as:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string GroupName;
    public DateTime Dt;
    .... other properties ....
}
```

And suppose I had the following `List<MyClass>` (showing it as a table since it seems the easiest way to describe the contents):

```
GroupName:       Dt:             Val:
Group1           2016/01/01      a
Group1           2016/01/02      b
Group1           2016/01/03      c
Group2           2016/01/01      d
Group2           2016/01/02      e
Group3           2016/01/01      f
Group3           2016/01/02      g
Group3           2016/01/03      h
```

And I'm looking to get from this list all the data:

1. Firstly grouped by `Dt`
2. Secondly grouped by `GroupName`

So, (and I'm sure this is wrong, but I'm hoping it'll explain what I'm looking for), I'd like to get an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, IEnumerable<MyClass>>>>`

My best attempt at managing to get this was the following:

```
return MyList
    .GroupBy(d => d.Dt)
    .GroupBy(grp => grp.ToList().GroupBy(d => d.GroupName));
```

I know this is wrong, but this is the only thing I could figure out.
How could I get what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Select`:

```
return MyList
    .GroupBy(d => d.Dt)
    .Select(grp => grp.GroupBy(d => d.GroupName));
```

To get exactly what you want you'd need an extra `GroupBy` after the `Select`:

```
var groups = MyList
    .GroupBy(d => d.Dt)
    .Select(grp => new { key = grp.Key, items = grp.GroupBy(d => d.GroupName) })
    .GroupBy(grp => grp.key, grp => grp.items);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Marcin, but I'm STILL stuck with returning even this as a group<group<results>> where I can iterate over `Dts` first and then `Groupnames` second - Would / should your solution accomplish this?

Comment: It is a nested group, but to clarify here's a more explicit version where you can `.` into everything and see what's going on:

    return MyList
        .GroupBy(d => d.Dt)
        .Select(g1 => new
                {
                  Dt = g1.Key,
                  Dts = g1.GroupBy(d => d.GroupName)
                          .Select(g2 => new
                                  {
                                     GroupName = g2.Key,
                                     GroupNames = g2
                                  })
                });

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, feel free to paste the edited version into your answer.

Comment: @JohnBustos Updated my answer with a query that gives you what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you both Marcin and @gzak - That truly wasn't something I'd have figured out myself and worked perfectly!!!! - **THANK YOU**

Comment: @gzak's comment was exactly what I needed (no extra group levels to traverse) thank you!